# String operations in XQuery

Tags: xml, string, xquery

My xml file has a line:

```
<asin ISBN="0001714600 9780001714601" code="aB1234Av">
```

I want to extract ISBN[0] i.e

> **0001714600** 9780001714601

or ISBN[1] i.e

> 0001714600 **9780001714601**

I tried substring and tokenize but its not working to my desire. Heres my code:

```
<strong>{for $asin in doc('amazon.xml')/asin/@ISBN
    return (tokenize($asin/data(.),'\s'))}</strong>

(OR)

<strong>{for $asin in doc('amazon.xml')/asin/@ISBN
    return (substring($asin/data(.),1))}</strong>
```

How should i get that value out of it?

Comment: Do you want to conditionally output one or the other value - or do you want to output them all? Are there always two values at the most?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tokenize(@ISBN, '\s')[1]` and `tokenize(@ISBN, '\s')[2]` should work perfectly well, or you could also do `substring-before(@ISBN, ' ')` and `substring-after(@ISBN, ' ')`

Comment: Well, substring() can be used (easily) only if it is known that only two values are represented in this way, which is why I opted for tokenize().

Comment: Sure. It's always hard to know what code is most appropriate when we only have a single example of input data to go on, and no general rules; that's why I gave two options.

Answer (score 3):

Using `tokenize()` is OK.

If you take things apart, it becomes easier to see what happens:

```
let $input := <asin ISBN="0001714600 9780001714601" code="aB1234Av"/>
let $isbn-string := $input/@ISBN/string()
let $isbn-items := tokenize($isbn-string, '\s')
    return
        for $isbn-item in $isbn-items
            return <strong>{$isbn-item}</strong>
```

You first fetch the string value of the @ISBN attribute, then tokenize it, then iterate over the tokenized items, outputting them one by one.

PS: In XPath, positional predicates start with 1, so ISBN[0] would return nothing.